# In Spring Security allowing some endpoints without authentication

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I am working on spring security, I want some controller endpoints should need authentication, some should not. I have created one security config. and tried

```
@Bean
    public SecurityConfigurerAdapter<DefaultSecurityFilterChain, HttpSecurity> securityConfigurerAdapter() {
        return new SecurityConfigurerAdapter<DefaultSecurityFilterChain, HttpSecurity>() {
            @Override
            public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                http.cors(cor -> {
            cor.disable();
        }).authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeRequests -> {
            authorizeRequests.requestMatchers("/api/**").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("api/login", "api/register")
                    .permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/api/auth").authenticated();
        })

                .sessionManagement(sessionManagement -> {
                    sessionManagement.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
                }).authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
                .addFilterBefore(authFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }
```

but still it is for login and it is giving http error as 403 forbidden.
[screen shot of postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sK4Of.png)

and giving warning as `Cache miss for ERROR dispatch to '/error' (previous null). Performing MatchableHandlerMapping lookup. This is logged once only at WARN level, and every time at TRACE.`

I have tried it by another way as

```
@Bean
    public SecurityConfigurerAdapter<DefaultSecurityFilterChain, HttpSecurity> securityConfigurerAdapter() {
        return new SecurityConfigurerAdapter<DefaultSecurityFilterChain, HttpSecurity>() {
            @Override
            public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeRequests -> {
                    authorizeRequests.requestMatchers("/api/application/**").permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers("api/login", "api/register").permitAll().requestMatchers("/api/auth")
                            .authenticated();
                }).build();

            }
        };
    }
```

but then it is giving error as 403 unathorized.
I have got info on [How to allow certain endpoint in spring security to be allowed without authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52744502/how-to-allow-certain-endpoint-in-spring-security-to-be-allowed-without-authentic) but in spring boot 3.2.0 `http.cors()` is deprecated.

Comment: first of all why are you returning a `SecurityConfigurerAdapter` and not a `SecurityFilterChain` as in the docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/passwords/index.html#servlet-authentication-unpwd second of all you should delete your `authFilter` handing out jwts to browsers is dangerous and not recommended, and there is a reason why that type of authentication does not exist in spring security, so why have you ignored that and built custom dangerous security? Why dont you read the spring security docs before asking here?

Comment: Show your request with headers. Show your Spring Security `DEBUG` logs.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is that when an error happens, Spring send the user to the /error endpoint, but in your case that is protected, so when the users tries to access it, it gets denied and the user gets a 403 instead.

Permit anyone to access the error endpoint:

```
@Bean
public SecurityConfigurerAdapter<DefaultSecurityFilterChain, HttpSecurity> securityConfigurerAdapter() {
    return new SecurityConfigurerAdapter<DefaultSecurityFilterChain, HttpSecurity>() {
        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.cors(cor -> {
        cor.disable();
    }).authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeRequests -> {
        authorizeRequests
        .requestMatchers("error").permitAll()
        .requestMatchers("/api/**").permitAll()
        .requestMatchers("api/login", "api/register")
                .permitAll()
        .requestMatchers("/api/auth").authenticated();
    })

            .sessionManagement(sessionManagement -> {
                sessionManagement.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
            }).authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
            .addFilterBefore(authFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    return http.build();
}
```

Comment: Its a better idea to create a filter and add it to the SecurityFilterChain as in the docs.